# No complex type created after updating the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have 1 stored procedure returning a complex type that was showing earlier with a suffix `_Result`. Then I updated the procedure and went to my `.edmx` file and deleted that procedure from these 3 places:

1. Under "Complex Types"
2. Under "Function Imports"
3. Under "Stored Procedures/ Functions"

I saved the `.EDMX` file, and right-clicked to "update the model from database". I then add the updated stored procedure and hit "Save" again.

But this time, I don't see the complex type. What I have tried

- Declared default values to my parameters
- `SET FMTONLY ON`
- `SET FMTONLY OFF`

But nothing works which can give me the complex type back. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be touching `FMTONLY` because that's exactly how the EDMX tooling discovers procedure result shapes.

Comment: @Dai I have tried without adding FMTONLY also but no luck. Still not getting the complex type.

Comment: If you run `SET FMTONLY ON` and execute the stored proc do you see any errors?

Comment: No @MartinSmith

Comment: What do you get if you run `select * from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(object_id('dbo.Yourprocedure'), 0)` does it show the correct resultset description?